# Connecting to MindWave through COM port?

Tags: ruby, serial-port

Has anyone here tried connecting to the MindWave device through the COM port associated with the bluetooth device? Is it better to just connect through the Thinkgear Connector?  My target language is Ruby and I was thinking of using the serial-port library.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to the serial port directly you will have to parse binary data which, actually, ThinkGear Connect socket protocol is for (all related is [here](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_connector_tgc)) TGSP is JSON-based protocol so dealing with it in Ruby is piece of cake (below is an extract from documentation at the link above)

> ThinkGear Socket Protocol (TGSP) is a JSON-based protocol for the
>   transmission and receipt of ThinkGear brainwave data between a client
>   and a server. TGSP was designed to allow languages and/or frameworks
>   without a standard serial port API (e.g. Flash and most scripting
>   languages) to easily integrate brainwave-sensing functionality through
>   socket APIs.

So I'd suggest you deal with TG socket protocol (I assume you don't run Ruby on an embedded device, for if you do, you will definitely need to parse data from TGAM chip by hand) rather than parse on your own, but don't forget you will have to have ThinkGear Connector software up and running everywhere you wish your code to run at.